# How to force a specific key to execute the next action in c ++

Tags: c++, cin, cout, getchar

The library I can use is:

```
 #include<iostream>
 #include<vector>
 #include<fstream>
 #include<string>
```

Would you be able to exit the program by typing a specific character without using another library?
 hope it works as soon as I hit it without hitting the Enter key.

Comment: That would require a system specific library.

Comment: What do you mean by saying exit? Does not return 0 command work?

Comment: I want to make any action run when any key is pressed. Termination is one of them.

Comment: No. In standard C++ there's no concept of a key press. You only have input and output streams, and most consoles won't send input to your program until you press enter. Therefore what you want is not possible without a system specific library.